# Internet Explorer Multiple Backgrounds bug?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, background-image

I have an element that uses 2 backgrounds, one of which is a linear-gradient. E.g.:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(33, 212, 37, 0.1),rgba(33, 212, 37, 0.1)), url(http://placekitten.com/g/200/200);
```

Then using javascript I switch the background with a different linear background and image.

This works in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE11, if the image I switch to is large, nothing happens. If I use a very small image, then it works fine in IE also.

Example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8N8u7QB3TIJ6NJmW3id8?p=preview

This seems to be some strange bug. Any solutions?

Comment: Did you use any prefixes?

Comment: @JimFahad No, as you can see in the example. I don't think IE11 needs a prefix for linear-gradient or anything I am using here.

Comment: @Se7en Did you find a solution?